# Reduce Formula Size (Case)

Tags: formula-field, administration, limits

I want to create a formula (text) that combines (parts) of two fields in some scenarios.

Example: If the 'BillingPostalCode__c' starts with *90* and the first 9 characters of the 'NormalisedCompanyName__c' equals *SIEMENSAG* then I would like to combine the first 3 characters of the 'BillingStreetCorrected__c' with the 'NormalisedCompanyName__c'.

> NormalisedCompanyName__c (text) = SIEMENSAG_Some_Text
>
> BillingPostalCode__c (formnula, 154 chars) = 90123
>
> BillingStreetCorrected__c (text) = MyStreet
>
> Formula Result: MySSIEMENSAG_Some_Text

Unfortunately, right now I do not see any other solution than repeating 'BillingStreetCorrected__c' million times. I'm close to *Compiled formula is too big to execute* Limit but I need to add additional case results.

I hope that anyone has a suggestion to reduce characters and/or to build a more beautiful formula!?

Best,
Stefan

```
LEFT(
CASE(
    LEFT(
        LEFT(BillingPostalCode__c, 2) + 
        NormalisedCompanyName__c,
        11), 
    '38VOLKSWAGE', SUBSTITUTE(BillingStreetCorrected__c, 'BRIEFFACH', ''),
    '91SIEMENSAG', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '90SIEMENSAG', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '70DAIMLERAG', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '81SIEMENSAG', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '45SIEMENSAG', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '13SIEMENSAG', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '71DAIMLERAG', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '10DAIMLERAG', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '10DEUTSCHEB', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '53DEUTSCHET', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '76SIEMENSAG', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '80BMWAG', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '85AUDIAG', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '67BASFSE', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    '01TECHNISCH', BillingStreetCorrected__c,
    ''
    ),3)
+ NormalisedCompanyName__c
```

Comment: Hi Stefan - for clarity: are you running into the "maximum number of characters" limit, or the  "compiled formula is too big to execute" limit? If it's the compile size limit, are BillingStreetCorrected__c or NormalisedCompanyName__c also formula fields? Also, you may want to check out the Salesforce doc on reducing formula sizes: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/218/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_formula_size_tipsheet.pdf

Comment: Hi @shannonsans, thanks for your question. I edited the post.

1. BillingStreetCorrected__c, NormalisedCompanyName__c are text fields. BillingPostalCode__c is a more or less tiny formula (154 chars).
2. Error Message is "Compiled formula is too big to execute".

Thanks for the link. :-) Best, Stefan